# Angular.js routeProvider

Tags: angularjs, route-provider

I'm new with angular.js and having a hard time understanding the routeProvider. in the code below:

```
.when('/notes', {
  templateUrl: 'templates/pages/notes/index.html'
})
```

what does the first ('/notes', {...}); stand for?
attached is the full code snippet:

```
angular.module('NoteWrangler', ['ngRoute'])
.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {

$routeProvider
.when('/notes', {
  templateUrl: 'templates/pages/notes/index.html'
})
.when('/users', {
  templateUrl: 'templates/pages/users/index.html'
})
  .when('/notes/new', {
  templateUrl: 'templates/pages/notes/edit.html'
})
    .otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/notes'    
});
}]);
```

Comment: when url is `baseURL/notes` -> load this template in the view. It really is not that hard.

Answer (score 0):

When `mydomain.com/#/notes` link is accessed the template `mydomain.com/templates/pages/notes/index.html` will be fetched and displayed.

Does that make sense?

Comment: based on what you're saying, if I was to write mydomain.com/notes/new, the page loaded would be templates/pages/notes/edit.html ?
if so, it basically gives us a shortcut to writing the whole path to the file. did I get it right?

Comment: Yes except you need the `#` `mydomain.com/#/notes/new` Indicates its a local route and should new be fetched as a request.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider

Comment: No problem. Go ahead and select my answer as correct! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When there is #/notes in your url after domain name it will redirect to the template which is specified in templateUrl for that route.
In the above case:
url : domain/#/notes
template: index.html

Answer (score 0):

```
.when('/notes', {
  templateUrl: 'templates/pages/notes/index.html'
})
```

It means

when client(browser) requests for the route "/notes"
e.g. http://localhost:8080/notes  or http://yourwebsite/notes

angular loads the HTML page **index.html** found in that
path 'templates/pages/notes/index.html'

In your app you need to have that folder structure

same goes for
`'/users'` and `'/notes/new'`

**Otherwise** is a catch-all

```
.otherwise({
   redirectTo: '/notes'    
});
```

any other route that you didn't specify is handled by this,
thus in your code, you force redirection to /notes (which I assume is your home page)

additional example:
you can also have

```
.when('/notes', {
  template: '<div>Hello world!</div>'
})
```

which will give you HTML directly instead of a template HTML page

> **TL DR;** when this route (`'/notes'`) is encountered I'll give you this `templateUrl` HTML page